# Android: how to execute callback after worker thread finished working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have a task of uploading a file to the net.

I want the UI to have progress bar dialog at the meantime

and when the upload is done, I want to close the progress bar and let another task run.

It has to be sequential (meaning task2 only after task1 finishes)

How can I do it? I think of using callbacks, but what is the best way to call new thread with callback in android?

Comment: Uh - why not have your "download finished" code simply spawn a new thread?

Comment: can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already know AsyncTask here is a way to do it in pseudocode:

```
UploadTask extends AsyncTask
    onPreExecute
        create progressbar
    doInBackground
        do upload
        update progress
    onProgressUpdate
        setProgress on progressbar
    onPostExecute
        dismiss progressbar
        start task2
```

If you do not know AsyncTask you can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html